# Entity container lookup columns

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, salesforce

I am successfully using an Entity Container to allow users to enter a new contact.

Is there any way to control what columns are shown when the user searches for an Account Name? At the moment 5 columns are shown, but I would like to display different columns and change the display order.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you post a code snippet of what you've already got? It would help us help you. :)

Comment: The code I am using to call the dynamic entity is:-

      var itemClass : Class = MetadataUtil.getItemClassForType( _selectedEntity );
      if ( itemClass == DynamicEntity ){
       var acc:DynamicEntity = new itemClass( _selectedEntity );
       acc.OwnerId="RK ITTest";
       //acc.LastName="Test Surname"
       //acc.AccountId="0012000000SYjtB"
       _createFieldContainer.render(acc);
      }

I am calling the Contact object.

The issue is when you click on one of the search boxes in the Contact screen, is it possible to control what fields are listed like in SalesForce??

Answer (score 1):

What you may want to look at is using a FieldContainer.  EntityContainer uses the layout metadata, so unless you can control the layout info - you may or may not be able to control that view.  A FieldContainer uses the LabelandField component, which allows you to bind it to particular fields.

Hope that helps.